# Can we leave the Dubai airport during a long layover; do we need a visa?

Tags: visas, airports, layovers, dubai, serbian-citizens

My friend and I have a 10 hour layover In Dubai. I was wondering could we visit Burj Khalifa in that time. Only problem is that we are arriving at the airport at 23.20h and it is on Monday. We don't want to go at the top of the building, only to see it. I was wondering if it's safe to walk at night, and do we have enough time for that? We are from Serbia, and I don't know if we need visa for that.

Comment: Note that the observation deck at the Burj Khalifa isn't open 24 hours a day. Looking at [their website](https://tickets.atthetop.ae/atthetop/Step0_BookingInfo.aspx) now, it seems the first entry time is at 10am and the last is at 11:45pm (this seems to depend on the day: it's 8:30am and 11pm for a day in a few weeks). [The Dubai Mall](https://thedubaimall.com/en/plan-your-visit/opening-hours) is open 10am-2am. So with your flight schedule, you'd be able to go see the Burj Khalifa from the outside, but would likely not be able to get to the observation deck or spend much time at the mall.

Answer (score 2):

Although you are able to Transit Without Visa (TWOV) through Dubai, as a Serbian passport holder, you must obtain a visa to leave the airport during the layover. 
You can use the [Emirates tool](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) to check your visa requirements. It does indicates that you need apply in advance for a visa, should you decide to leave the airport.

If you are travelling to or stopping in UAE with Emirates or Etihad, you can apply for your UAE visa through the website’s [Manage a booking tool after booking your flight](http://www.dubaivisa.net/online.html).

Otherwise, you would have to apply for a visa at the [Embassy of the United Arab Emirates in Belgrade](http://beta.uae-embassy.ae/Embassies/bl/Content/6402).

Burj Khalifa and the Dubai Mall are about 15 km from the airport, 15-20 minutes by taxi.

As for safety, Dubai and the UAE rate very highly in this regard, by both residents and tourists, men and women.